# Batch How do i execute a command on every .m4p file in all Sub dir

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

Basically i want to run this in ever Sub folder

```
for %%i in (*.m4a) do faad "%%i"
for %%i in (*.wav) do oggenc "%%i"
for %%i in (*.m4a) do del "%%i"
for %%i in (*.wav) do del "%%i"
```

it works great but i  have to manually change dir and re run
eg.

```
cd res  
cd music
for %%i in (*.m4a) do faad "%%i"
for %%i in (*.wav) do oggenc "%%i"
for %%i in (*.m4a) do del "%%i"
for %%i in (*.wav) do del "%%i"
cd..
cd Sounds
for %%i in (*.m4a) do faad "%%i"
for %%i in (*.wav) do oggenc "%%i"
for %%i in (*.m4a) do del "%%i"
for %%i in (*.wav) do del "%%i"
cd..
```

and the list goes on. Problem is i have hundreds of sub folders, so it would take forever
is there a way i can run my little script automatically in All sub directory's starting with a defined dir
such as

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b /s *.m4p`) do faad.exe "%%f"
```

Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out for my self
All i have to do is point to the dir with the m4a files and the code does the rest,
It will look though every sub folder also

cd Music

for /r %%i in (*.m4a) do faad "%%i"

for /r %%i in (*.wav) do oggenc "%%i"

for /r %%i in (*.m4a) do del "%%i"

for /r %%i in (*.wav) do del "%%i"

For your information.This scpipt Looks for m4a files, uses faad to convert to  wave file`s
The wave files are then get converted to Ogg format using oggenc
The m4a files are deleted
The wave files are deleted

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to do the following so that you won't lose your source .m4a files if conversion process fails:

```
for /r %%i in (*.m4a) do call :convert %%i
goto :end

:convert
  set M4A=%1
  set WAV=%M4A:.m4a=.wav%
  set OGG=%M4A:.m4a=.ogg%
  faad %M4A%
  if not exist %WAV% (echo %M4A% not converted.) else (oggenc %WAV%      )
  if not exist %OGG% (echo %WAV% not converted.) else (del    %M4A% %WAV%) 
goto :EOF

:end
```